# Access HTTP server on port 8080 in Ubuntu

Tags: apache2

Access http server on port 8080 on Ubuntu

**netstat -tulpn output:**

```
Connexions Internet actives (seulement serveurs)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Adresse locale          Adresse distante        Etat       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:13000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1941/bearerbox  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:13001           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1941/bearerbox  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1141/mysqld     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:13131           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1994/smsbox     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5900            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2844/vino-server
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5941          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2200/teamviewerd
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1616/dnsmasq    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1065/sshd       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3149/cupsd      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1227/postgres   
tcp6       0      0 :::5800                 :::*                    LISTEN      2844/vino-server
tcp6       0      0 :::5900                 :::*                    LISTEN      2844/vino-server
**tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      7062/apache2**    
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      7062/apache2    
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1065/sshd       
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      3149/cupsd      
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:631             0.0.0.0:*                           1117/cups-browsed
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:43858           0.0.0.0:*                           785/avahi-daemon: r
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           785/avahi-daemon: r
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:42579           0.0.0.0:*                           1204/dhclient   
udp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*                           1616/dnsmasq    
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           1204/dhclient   
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                785/avahi-daemon: r
udp6       0      0 :::52679                :::*                                785/avahi-daemon: r
udp6       0      0 :::3779                 :::*                                1204/dhclient
```

**NMAP:** my WAN IP adress is `41.125.130.148`:

```
nmap 41.125.130.148

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-06-14 19:32 CET
Nmap scan report for 41.125.130.148
Host is up (0.0012s latency).
Not shown: 996 closed ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
21/tcp open  ftp
22/tcp open  ssh
23/tcp open  telnet
80/tcp open  http

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 20.30 seconds
```

**My Apache config `/etc/apache2`:**

```
 cat /etc/apache2/ports.conf 
# If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
# have to change the VirtualHost statement in
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

Listen 80
Listen 8080
<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

I test access `localhost:8080/html/playsms` it's OK but on `125.130.148:8080/html/playsms`  it's Ko and down

Answer (score 1):

What is this IP `125.130.148`? You state that your WAN IP is `41.125.130.148`, so either you should check against the WAN IP and/or against the LAN IP but you will probably hit against the NAT loopback of your DSL modem - router.

A possible solution to bypass the NAT loopback is to set up a local DNS pointing to a local domain.

Additionally you should check your sites configurations at `/etc/apache2/sites-available` and /etc/apache2/sites-enabled`, what IPs - Domain names and Ports do you enable there?

Example of a Virtual Host listening on **any** IP - Domain on Port **80**:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
     ServerName foobar.com # this is your domain name
     ServerAlias www.foobar.com  # an alias using www prefix
     DocumentRoot /srv/www/foobar.com/public_html # where your puclic documents (HTML) lives
     ErrorLog /var/log/foobar.com/apache2/foobar_error.log # error logs for the domain
     CustomLog /var/log/foobar/apache2/foobar_access.log # access logs for the domain
</VirtualHost>
```